# Check if phone got sensor at installing application

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-install-apk

Basically I am wondering what title says. I searched on internet and coudn't really find answear. 
So anyone know's if is possible to check if phone got specific sensor ( example linear-acceleration ) before you install apk. I don't know maybe when you agree to permission gives you warring " you dont have this sensor " or something ?

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.xxxxx" android:required="true" />
in your androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Nice idea, thank you.  hadn't thought of it.  But seems like not working for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that came into my mind is to dig through the 'Supported Devices' list on the google play developer console and only choose devices which have the sensor you need.

Comment: That's one option yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check the availabilty of sensor in your device

```
boolean sensoravailable;

sensoravailable = sensorMgr.registerListener(this,sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);

if(sensoravailable) 
{
.
.
}
```

In the Manifest u can check Like this

```
<uses-feature 
android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" 
android:required="true" />
```

Following are the sensor You can check in manifest : refer-> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER

Added in API level 8
String FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes an accelerometer.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"

FEATURE_SENSOR_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE

Added in API level 21
String FEATURE_SENSOR_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes an ambient temperature sensor.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.ambient_temperature"

FEATURE_SENSOR_BAROMETER

Added in API level 9
String FEATURE_SENSOR_BAROMETER
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a barometer (air pressure sensor.)

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.barometer"

FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS

Added in API level 8
String FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a magnetometer (compass).

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.compass"

FEATURE_SENSOR_GYROSCOPE

Added in API level 9
String FEATURE_SENSOR_GYROSCOPE
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a gyroscope.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"

FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE

Added in API level 20
String FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a heart rate monitor.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.heartrate"

FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE_ECG

Added in API level 21
String FEATURE_SENSOR_HEART_RATE_ECG
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The heart rate sensor on this device is an Electrocardiogram.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.heartrate.ecg"

FEATURE_SENSOR_LIGHT

Added in API level 7
String FEATURE_SENSOR_LIGHT
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a light sensor.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.light"

FEATURE_SENSOR_PROXIMITY

Added in API level 7
String FEATURE_SENSOR_PROXIMITY
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a proximity sensor.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.proximity"

FEATURE_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY

Added in API level 21
String FEATURE_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a relative humidity sensor.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.relative_humidity"

FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER

Added in API level 19
String FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a hardware step counter.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"

FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR

Added in API level 19
String FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR
Feature for getSystemAvailableFeatures() and hasSystemFeature(String): The device includes a hardware step detector.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"

Comment: I got "  if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) == null) {} " and as far I know this is more correctly then your solution. But this is when you launch app. I want to know if there is something to find out before.

Comment: i dont think u can check that before installation. Because it doesn't allow to access anything without user permission

Comment: u can check it soon after instalation during launch screen

Comment: U might not be having access to data before user accept installation. It is against the privacy policy. I am not 100% sure about it.. U may ask someelse too.. As per my knowledge we cannot do that

Comment: Well thank you for your help. Guess will have to do it this way.

Comment: Well looks like you can do ACCELEROMETER but not linear.